# In C#, is it possible to cast a List<Child> to List<Parent>?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I want to do something like this:

```
List<Child> childList = new List<Child>();
...
List<Parent> parentList = childList;
```

However, because parentList is a *List* of Child's ancestor, rather than a direct ancestor, I am unable to do this. Is there a workaround (other than adding each element individually)?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but there's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569774/ienumerablet-conversion

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Casting directly is not allowed because there's no way to make it typesafe. If you have a list of giraffes, and you cast it to a list of animals, you could then put a tiger into a list of giraffes!  The compiler wouldn't stop you, because of course a tiger may go into a list of animals. The only place the compiler can stop you is at the unsafe conversion.

In C# 4 we'll be supporting covariance and contravariance of SAFE interfaces and delegate types that are parameterized with reference types.  See here for details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: Even worse, if the compiler let you do that, your list would end up smaller than expected because the tiger would eat a few of the giraffes.

Comment: Does anything change if the type parameter for the "parent" is an interface? It appears that a covariant collection interface solves OP's original problem.

Answer (score 101):

Using LINQ:

```
List<Parent> parentList = childList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

[Documentation for `Cast<>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

Comment: Note that this creates a copy of `childList`, exactly like the not-using-LINQ version by @Andre Pena.

Comment: List<Parent> parentList = childList.OfType<Parent>().ToList(); also works, and is preferable in cases where you are less sure of the content of the starting list.

Comment: @dtb, you get a new list, but I suspect there's a good chance that the objects in the list are the same objects.

Comment: If Child inherits from Parent, then you can be 100% certain that the cast will work anyway.

Comment: Besides, C# 4 will bring in more convenient conversion, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183(VS.100).aspx

Comment: lextm: not for lists.  `List<>`s are neither covariant nor contravariant.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this exactly what the post author tried to do, which does NOT work. At run time you will get a System.InvalidCastException, because the type safe collection does not allow the cast. (Using Linq doesn't change a thing). See what Eric Lippert wrote.

Comment: The thing you are missing is that this construction creates a brand new list, which will not throw any exceptions at run time.

Comment: @recursive true, so you can use the new list of Parent objects to iterate over,etc. But the List<Parent> is a new object and not a reference to the original, so if you remove one of its elements, the original List<Child> will not be modified, for example.

Answer (score 16):

Back in 2009 Eric teased us that things would change in C# 4. So where do we stand today?

*The classes used in my answer can be found at the bottom. To make this easier to follow, we will use a `Mammal` class as "parent", and `Cat` and `Dog` classes as "children". Cats and dogs are both mammals, but a cat is not a dog and a dog is not a cat.*

This still isn't legal, and can't be:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();

List<Mammal> mammals = cats;
```

Why not? Cats are mammals, so why can't we assign a list of cats to a `List<Mammal>`?

Because, if we were allowed to store a reference to a `List<Cat>` in a `List<Mammal>` variable we would then be able to compile the following code to add a dog to a list of cats:

```
mammals.Add(new Dog());
```

We mustn't allow that! Remember, `mammals` is just a reference to `cats`. `Dog` does not descend from `Cat` and has no business being in a list of `Cat` objects.

[Starting with .NET Framework 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), several generic interfaces have covariant type parameters declared with the [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) Generic Modifier keyword introduced in  C# 4. Amongst these interfaces is [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx) which of course is implemented by `List<T>`.

That means we **can** now cast a `List<Cat>` to an `IEnumerable<Mammal>`:

```
IEnumerable<Mammal> mammalsEnumerable = cats;
```

We can't add a new `Dog` to `mammalsEnumerable` because `IEnumerable<out T>` is a "read-only" interface i.e. it has no `Add()` method, but we *can* now use `cats` wherever a `IEnumerable<Mammal>` can be consumed. For example, we can concatenate `mammalsEnumerable` with a `List<Dog>` to return a new sequence:

```
void Main()
{
    List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat> { new Cat() };
    IEnumerable<Mammal> mammalsEnumerable =
        AddDogs(cats); // AddDogs() takes an IEnumerable<Mammal>
    Console.WriteLine(mammalsEnumerable.Count()); // Output: 3. One cat, two dogs.
}

public IEnumerable<Mammal> AddDogs(IEnumerable<Mammal> parentSequence)
{
    List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog> { new Dog(), new Dog() };
    return parentSequence.Concat(dogs);
}
```

---

Class definitions:

```
public abstract class Mammal { }

public class Cat: Mammal { }

public class Dog : Mammal { }
```

Comment: ++ for the only one to find the crux of the problem: read-only interface

Comment: Gist? This works with IEnumerable<T> but not List<T>

Answer (score -1):

Don't do this:

```
List<Parent> parentList = childList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

A child class should not be used as parent, if you want to pass a list as parameter of a method that receives a `list<parent>`, you need to change the method parameter using IEnumerable, more info  [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
public void methodA(IEnumerable<parent> param){}
```

Now you can use this method like this:

```
var oListChild = new List<child>();
methodA(oListChild);
```

Comment: List<T> already is (implements) IEnumerable<T> (which in term implements IEnumerable). The documentation link you included is useful, but this answer doesn't explain how one would create (or cast) an IEnumerable<TChild> to IEnumerable<TParent>.

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can do it like

```cs
var result = List.And(x => x.Parent.All(b => b.ParentId == value));
```

Comment: This seems to be related to an ORM object hierarchy. More context is needed for a useful example.

Answer (score -3):

You can do this by using a Linq approach of the apply extension method, i.e.:

```cs
List<Parent> parentList = childList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```